# jQuery's :hidden selector not working in IE9 Quirks Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, hidden, quirks-mode

For the next project my team is working on, we have an ASP.NET/HTML 4 project that we're (slowly) upgrading to MVC 4.0/HTML 5.  It is a requirement that this setup work on IE 9, but we can't yet fully upgrade to HTML 5 for a number of reasons.

The problem I am trying to solve involves the simple task of toggling a callout, based on the jQuery `:hidden` selector.  While it is possible to get the callout to appear, getting it to hide is causing me some trouble.

We have an MVC partial with the following markup:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='my-styles.css' />

<h4>Information</h4>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PersonName, "Person's Name")
    @Html.InputFor(m => m.PersonName)
    <a href='#' id='info-link'>[ ! ]</a>
</div>

<div id='info-callout' class='callout hidden'>
    <div class='callout-before'></div><div class='callout-main'>
        This is the name of the person this form refers to.
    </div>
</div>

<script src='this-form.js'></script>
```

...and inside of this-form.js:

```
var MyTeamCallout = function($control, $callout) {
    var pub = {};
    pub.$control = $control;
    pub.$callout = $callout;

    pub.RegisterClickEvent = function () {
      pub.$control.click(function () {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();

          // Repositioning of the control removed for purposes of this post.
          if(pub.$callout.is(':hidden')) {
              pub.$callout.show();
          }
          else {
              pub.$callout.hide();
          }
      });
    }

    return pub;
};

// --- Functional Code... -----------------------------------
var $link = $('#info-link'),
    $callout = $('#info-callout');

$(document).ready(function () {
    var calloutObject = new MyTeamCallout($link, $callout);
    calloutObject.RegisterClickEvent();
});
```

...Finally, with the given CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.callout {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    /* Left/Top assigned by JavaScript, normally */
}

.callout-before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    left: -1em;

    /* SNIP: Borders are used to create a CSS triangle. */
}

.callout-main
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 10em;
}
```

When I run this in IE9, I can cause the callout to appear, but not to hide again.  I am showing no JavaScript errors in F12 Developer Tools.

**Questions:**
A) Are there known compatibility issues with the `:hidden` selector in IE9 Quirks Mode?
B) If so, what would be a better vehicle to overcome these limitations?*

*: The problem in question is a little more complex than I've posted here, but our current solution uses the `:hidden` selector.  I'm trying to preserve that if at all possible.

Comment: I don't see any documentation about it, but I doubt that `:hidden` works in QuirksMode as a psuedo selector. You probably need to instead make a direct comparison against the visibility / display state / opacity of the element.

Comment: I looked for documentation as well and found nothing.  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at [http://quirksmode.org/](http://quirksmode.org/), but unfortunately `:hidden` is not a `CSS2/3 psuedo selector` so there's no information about it there either. I'd be interested in learning if this resolves your issue or not.

Comment: jQuery implements these selectors and pseudo-selectors for browsers that don't support them natively. What version of jQuery are you using? Also, are you checking for the element having a non-visible `display` value, or a `visibility` value? Another way is to use class names rather than directly manipulating CSS values - ie: `.addClass('show|hide')` and `.removeClass('show|hide')`, (pick show or hide based on your preferences)

Comment: For instance you already have a class name of `hidden` applied to your `#info-callout` element. Simply check whether the element `.hasClass('hidden');` and if not, add it. If so, remove it. Easy peasy.

Comment: @Derek: I am using jQuery 1.9.1; earlier in the process, we discovered some compatibility issues with jQuery 2.0.0 and later.

I'll go the extra step further that @Ohgodwhy mentioned and do a check against `display` being set to `none`, that way my team isn't tied down to a class name that we could forget about in three months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any documentation about it, but I doubt that :hidden works in QuirksMode as a psuedo selector. You probably need to instead make a direct comparison against the visibility / display state / opacity of the element.

Comment: Added a method to my Callout Javascript that checks visibility, display state, and element opacity to determine if it is hidden or not, which resolved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not support Quirks mode. The lowest browser they support (or have ever supported) is IE6 in Standards mode.

So the fact that something has broken is not a surprise; in fact, if *anything* in jQuery works in Quirks mode, you should consider it lucky.

I strongly recommend trying to bring the site into standards mode as soon as possible by adding a doctype. This doesn't necessarily mean you have to go all HTML5, but you should consider at least making the minimal switch to standards mode to be a priority.

If you're worried about your layout breaking in standards mode, try adding

```
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
```

to the top of your CSS file; this will set the standards mode box model to emulate quirks mode, and will mitigate a large portion of the layout glitches that occur due to the switch.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was just concerned about my script issue and figuring out how to determine hiddenness without the `:hidden` selector.  But there are other things on this same setup that I'm bearing your advice in mind; given how much jQuery I'm using, there's actually some pretty extensive compatibility (with some interesting 'quirks', like left and top styling doing awkward things.)

Still, thanks for the info!